# AWS: Multiple Step functions with Single Eventbridge rule for failure notification

Tags: aws-step-functions, aws-event-bridge

Is it possible to have single rule in eventbridge for multiple step functions to handle failure notification

Basically I am expecting something like this

```
arn:aws:states:us-east-1:1234567890:stateMachine:sf-dev-xyz-*            ---> Wildcard
```

> ```
> Event pattern
>
> {
>   "source": ["aws.states"],
>   "detail-type": ["Step Functions Execution Status Change"],
>   "detail": {
>     "status": ["FAILED"],
>     "stateMachineArn": ["arn:aws:states:us-east-1:1234567890:stateMachine:sf-dev-xyz-*"]
>   }
> }
> ```

I am trying it in AWS Eventbridge - AWS StepFunctions - AWS Glue environment

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use prefix matching: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-event-patterns-content-based-filtering.html
My guess is that you can replace

```
{
    ...
    "stateMachineArn": ["arn:aws:states:us-east-1:1234567890:stateMachine:sf-dev-xyz-*"]
}
```

with

```
{
    ...
    "stateMachineArn": [{"prefix": "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:1234567890:stateMachine:sf-dev-xyz-"}]
}
```

If that works, definitely give us an update!

Comment: It works for me, I needed to catch every single step functions error inside the organization.
With prefix and "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:1234567890:stateMachine:" i've been able to catch them all